# Laravel Beautymail: I want to route all emails to a database table for subsequent sending by a daemon ... how best?

Tags: laravel, email

I have a Laravel application which of course uses Beautymail to send e-mails, and what I'd like to do is to divert those emails into a database table instead.  Then, periodically, a daemon would run some command to actually send the emails.

I feel like this ought to be a fairly common requirement and so there should be some "elegant" way to do it.  Hence, does anyone out there have any suggestions and/or an example that I could follow?  *("Do Not Do A Thing Already Done ...")*

P.S.:  Yes, I know about "mail queueing" from the documentation, of course, but I guess what I'd really like to be pointed to are some actual, working examples (e.g. Github?) of ready-to-copy code that's already doing this ... sending the e-mail to an SQL table, sending from that table ... as much "I don't have to re-invent this stuff" stuff that anyone can very-helpfully point me to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a search of GitHub for "Laravel email database" produced several very good candidates that are currently maintained.  So, I picked one and put it in and it's working fine.

Some very nice features came along for the ride, such as the ability to insert message-tracking GIFs into the emails (automatically), allowing us to track that the message has been opened by someone and read.